# I can see Opportuntiy RMS in the report section, but can not see this in opportunity page

Tags: custom-field

I can see opportunity RMS field while preparing a report, but unable to find it in a single opportunity page. Can somebody help me where the field lies?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing the opportunity layout to include the field you would like to see? I am not sure what you mean with RMS field, is this a custom field you created?